# When I ran my code against a unit test I get an error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have this code. It returns an error "An Error Occurred Running your Script". I test it on terminal and gives the required results.

```
   function canIWatch(age) {
       var newAge   =  parseInt(age);
       var response;

       switch (true) {

         case (isNaN(newAge) || newAge <= 0):
           response = "Invalid Age.";
           break;

         case (newAge < 6):
           response = "You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.";
           break;

         case (newAge >= 6 && newAge < 17):
           response = "You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.";
           break;

         case (newAge >= 17 && newAge < 25):
           response = "You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.";
           break;

         case (newAge >= 25):
           response = "Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!";
           break;
         }
      return response;
   }
```

And here is the unit test code. I cant edit this .

```
describe('canIWatch tests', function () {
  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 6',    function () {
    expect(canIWatch(5)).toEqual('You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 17', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(15)).toEqual('You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 25', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(20)).toEqual('You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age above 25 than 6', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(30)).toEqual('Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!');
  });

  it('should return an appropriate message if provided age is invalid', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(-1)).toEqual('Invalid age.');
  });
});
```

I have tried the same with if-else loop and still get the same error.

Comment: `An Error Occurred Running your Script` is very broad, could you debug your code and tell us where exactly it fails to execute.

Comment: `switch (true) {` is probably the culprit.